# Error "git cat-file: could not get object info" in docker container after Docker desktop update

Tags: git, docker, docker-desktop

After update Docker desktop to 2.2.0.4 on win 10 I have had error "git cat-file: could not get object info" in container. Before update everething was ok.

Docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'

services:
  python:
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    container_name: python
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    volumes:
      - .:/usr/src/app
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3
WORKDIR /usr/src/app
COPY requirements.txt requirements.txt
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt
COPY . .
CMD ["flask", "run"]
```

git log:

```
root@97cb634b1d22:/usr/src/app# git ls-files --stage -- /usr/src/app/database/db.py
100644 e94b169ef5fc85022ac40b10a27646019230ae3f 0       database/db.py
root@97cb634b1d22:/usr/src/app# git cat-file -s e94b169ef5fc85022ac40b10a27646019230ae3f
fatal: git cat-file: could not get object info
```

Comment: Downgrading to 2.2.0.3 fixes the problem

Answer (score 0):

This can happen when an object does not exist in git database but used to and git still somehow knows about it. Out of curiosity, I did squash merge pushed the merged branch but not the commits that contributed to the squash merge, and then made a fresh clone of the remote and tried to cat-file one of the squashed commits. Got  "cat-file: could not get object info".